# Emacs backspace only one space

Tags: emacs, indentation, emacs24, backspace

How can I configure Emacs (24.3, OS X Yosemite, Prelude installed) to backspace only one space all the time? When I'm inside code blocks it will sometimes backspace 4 spaces without warning and I end up having to insert spaces back.

All of my code is indented with 2 spaces, never tabs.

Sorry if this is a basic question, just getting started with emacs.

Comment: Different modes do different things -- so, perhaps type `C-h k` and then your backspace key to see what function is attached to that key in whatever major / minor modes you are using.  Once you determine that, you can adjust the definition to your liking.

Comment: Says it's bound to command coffee-dedent-line-backspace, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `coffee-mode.el. How would I go about modifying the command to get the functionality I want?

Comment: There are a few ways to do that -- people who visit these threads / forums treat source code as sacred / holy.  I personally modify the heck out of my source code -- e.g., comment out `;;` line 236 (if you are using the same source code as the following link):  https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode/blob/master/coffee-mode.el  I'll post an alternative for the anti-modification-source-code-folks.  Essentially, nullifying the keymap assignment for `coffee-dedent-line-backspace` causes whatever the default fall-back is to take over.  But, modifying the source code requires byte-compiling again.

Comment: NOTE:  I haven't grepped prelude source code for all invocations of `coffee-dedent-line-backspace`, because I don't have that installed and you can probably take over from here.  I only looked at `coffee-mode.el`.  There could always be other keymap assignments in the prelude setup that assign `coffee-dedent-line-backspace` to backspace.  This is for the anti-modification-source-code-folks:  `(eval-after-load "coffee-mode" '(progn (define-key coffee-mode-map "\177" nil)))`

Comment: @lawlist that works perfectly! I'll accept it if you turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may be inserted into the `.emacs` or other similar initialization files.  The effect will be to nullify the previous `coffee-mode` key assignment of `\177`, which the original poster has indicated is the backspace key.

```
(eval-after-load "coffee-mode"
  '(progn
    (define-key coffee-mode-map "\177" nil)))
```

---

Alternatively, line 236 of the current version of `coffee-mode` can be commented out -- i.e., comment out `(define-key map "\177" 'coffee-dedent-line-backspace)` so that it has at least one preceding semi-colon.  Then, run `M-x byte-compile-file RET` and the path to the `coffee-mode.el` file and then `RET`.  The source code may be found at the following link:

http://www.github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode/blob/master/coffee-mode.el